# Is there an alternative to <iframe>?

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I've been trying to embed a url to a web app on wordpress, but unfortunately, the custom html widget literally does not allow the iframe tag.  What should I do?  Someone mentioned `<object>`, but that tag is apparently not allowed either.

Here's what wordpress says

[image: Here's what wordpress says]

Comment: @Phil: Did you mean formatting?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're asking. All I did was edit your question so the `<object>` tag and image was visible

Answer (score 1):

No.

You'll need to allow the tag. A quick Google search returned this:
https://wpquicktips.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/how-to-change-the-allowed-html-tags-for-wordpress/

Comment: I can't seem to be able to see/access editor, so I can't edit functions.php.  Surely there must be another way?

Comment: Nope. You've got to use an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). It's the tag that embeds other websites. You could alternatively do a bunch of Javascript coding and build whatever functionality you're trying to embed inside your own site, and fire off XHR requests to the web app, it's just a lot more work.

Comment: @intuitiveprogramming if you can't edit functions.php by yourself, get in touch with your server admin. They'll be able to change it for you.

Comment: I was told the documentation in https://wpquicktips.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/how-to-change-the-allowed-html-tags-for-wordpress/ is old and was meant for wordpress.org.  Turns out, it's not possible to embed link unless I pay a whopping $300.  What a ripoff.  Anyway, I appreciate the search.

Comment: What? No it's not. It's not out of date and is relevant to self-hosted WordPress sites. Just look at the WordPress code. https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/kses.php#L50 The array's still there, and the advice is still relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure who else you're talking to, but this is the correct answer.